# Better strategy for grouping of Abstract Algebra exam problems by sub-topic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, self-learning

I am studying for an Abstract Algebra exam by partitioning old exam problems based on the sub-topic I must understand in order to complete those type of problems. I have noticed that my partitioning has some sub-topics with many problems and other sub-topics with very few. I fear this has occurred because my partitioning is too broad and focuses on the types of objects in the problem and not the theorems and ideas the problem is intended to test my understanding of. What is an ideal strategy for partitioning this level of abstract algebra problems since my goal is to use the partition as a study aid?

[My partition of practice problems](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1c2QQ16Tnr3-HpYh40jy6-_06CjqaCYQ9OT2HOJPi3lg/view). There are many more practice problems but these go back 3 years and I had to stop somewhere.

Normally I would use any formal study guide or ask a professor for guidance but neither option is available. The best I have is a set of practice problems and 2 weeks of winter vacation to self study.

Comment: You could always go to a used bookstore, go to the math section, and try to find old cheap textbooks for more practice. I recently bought a Schaum textbook that was $6 and covers groups, rings, vector spaces (and more linear algebra), R-modules, polynomials, and galois theory. It has about a thousand practice problems with answers and 8 chapters and I got through a chapter (plus doing all the practice problems) today, so it is would probably be in the scope of 2 weeks.

Comment: thank you! I will do this today. I have used Schaum's textbooks in the past during freshman year but assumed that they would not have abstract algebra. Luckily I was wrong

Comment: happy to help, good luck! FYI they actually have a ton of advanced math textbooks, I even got one for advanced calculus for 6 bucks as well!